# need a help with creating a wordlist

Tags: password-cracking, dictionary

i wanna create a 8 digit long password list containing simple & capital letters+all the numbers,but not with stupid passwords like all the 8 digits in
numbers or simple or capital..should contain numbers and simple letters or numbers and capital letters or numbers and capital & simple letters both..with these three kind of combinations;is possible to have such a practical list? and so how can i create one?

Comment: "digits" implies the whole numbers from 0-9. I think you mean "characters". The opposite of capital letters is "lowercase letters", not "simple letters"

Comment: licence plates and partial ascii art are of consideration

Answer (score 0):

Too be honest, the GPU cracking speed of full a 8 character range is fast enough for most algorithms that it's easier to just bruteforce the entire range instead of relying on wordlists.

Otherwise your list is a quick google for "wordlist generator" away